# Mono Async Request Execution

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mono

Where and how does mono complete an asynchronous request? e.g. possibly by adding the callback to local thread pool, create a new thread to handle the callback etc?

So far I have been unable to determine exactly how it completes the request.

Edit to add example:

```
NetworkStream.BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
```

Comment: "an asynchronous request" could mean any number of things. Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: are you talking about something like BeginInvoke? Or about some operation returning an IAsynchResult?

Comment: Added example context.